# Unable to get handle to the class tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 1</title>
    <style>
        .detail { padding: 5px;}
        .hidden {display:none;}
        .unhidden {display: block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>
                <div class="master">Pre-foundation</div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    XYZ.......
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="master">Apple I</div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    XYZ.....
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="master">Apple II</div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    XYZ.....
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="master">Apple III</div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    XYZ.....
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="master">Apple IPO</div>
                <div class="hidden">
                   XYZ.....
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script   type="text/javascript"src="/Users/Documents/JS/jquery-1.6.2.js">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function show_alert()
    {
    alert("x! I am an alert box!");
    }
    show_alert();
    $(".master").click(function() {
      alert ("hello");
    });
</script>
</body>
```

I am having problems getting the click function to work. I am trying to expand the hidden text when the user clicks on the title of the paragraph.

The source of the jquery-1.6.2.js file is correct and I am able to open it in the browser. It also shows under the "script" tab of firebug.
If I delete the src="/Users/Documents/JS/jquery-1.6.2.js" from the code, I am able to see an alert box firing from show_alert();. But when I add the "src = .." in the code the show_alert(); stops working and I am not able to get handle to the 'master' class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting in the console if any ?

Comment: I didn't think you could specify both a source for a script tag and have content in it.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't get any errors, just cannot get hold of the "master" tag handle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you do not have your code wrapped with the [jQuery 'ready' function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  It needs to be wrapped in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
or
$(function() {});
```

Since you are using [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) you need to use jQuery instead of its alias of '$' after it is called:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function show_alert()
    {
        alert("x! I am an alert box!");
    }
    show_alert();
    jQuery(".master").click(function() {
      alert ("hello");
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WvBTM/5/) is a jsfiddle of this all working.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't waited for the DOM to be ready.

```
$(function() {

    // Execute any jQuery code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe, that jQuery does not exist, when your script is run. Therefore it throws an error and stops executing the rest. Try using jQuery from a relative path or from the google cdn: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.

- First, as noted by @Interstellar_Coder, you should have two separate script tags. One to load the external jQuery, and the other for your code.
- Second, you're calling `jQuery.noConflict()`, which gives up control of the `$` variable. Change your `$` to `jQuery` and it should work as long as your path to the jQuery file is valid.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/Documents/JS/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();

    function show_alert() {
        alert("x! I am an alert box!");
    }
    show_alert();

  <!-- no dollar sign -->
    jQuery(".master").click(function() {
        alert ("hello");
    });
</script>
```